# How do I score contract bonus points?

Tags: team-fortress-2

This one has me stumped, how do I score bonus contract points as the demo? (Gunmettle)

The instructions were to kill enemies while performing the objective, or something to that effect. I was pushing the cart on Borneo and killed enemies while defending it, and got no bonus.

What exactly am I doing wrong? I tried both melee and grenades, but still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely bugged on Payload maps.  I recommend trying it on a KOTH map like koth_suijin.

Edit: If it wasn't clear, you can only do contracts on Valve servers.  No other servers counts.  The easiest way to find Valve servers is using the Play Now button (or whatever the QuickPlay button is called now... top button in the default HUD, making sure your search settings are set to "Official servers").

Note: Bonus Points can be scored on ANY Valve server, not just GunMettle.

Comment: I think the problem is it has to be a **Valve** server (or at least a VAC-secure one). OP could be playing on a third-party server and be unable to earn points.

Comment: @Robotnik It **must** be a **Valve** server.  No other servers count.